# Is there any reason to use f bounded polymorpyism instead of type classes?

Tags: scala

Is there any reason to use f bounded polymorhism instead of type classes ?

They both solve the problem of making possible to write a function `f(a:A):A` where `A` must support a given set of operations (methods) (implement an interface/be an instance of a typeclass).

Comment: No, there is no reason. Well, that's a joke. I think your question is really opinion-based and broad.

Comment: These are different topics though their common denominator is types. Truth is (the practical truth) that you should use them together; just look at the sources of Cats or Scalaz - you will see both of them.

Comment: When is one better than the other if they solve the same problem?

Comment: A really blog post on this is https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Answer (score 2):

End-user code might be simpler, shorter and look better.

Example:

```
def first[A](s: Seq[A]): A = s.head
```

If `Seq` was a type class, users would have to write the following instead:

```
def first[A, F[_]](s: F[A])(implicit S: Seq[F]): A = S.head(s)
```

Comment: true, hence this macro : https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Simulacrum would not help with the left hand side of the type class version of `first`.